# CodeMirror as a JSF 2.0 composite component doesn't render properly in tab or dialog

Tags: jsf-2, codemirror

I just implemented CodeMirror (with some plugins) as a JSF 2.0 composite component (see code below). This component is working just fine as long as it's not placed inside some tab or dialog (anything that is not visible just after the page is loaded). When in tab or dialog, it seems like component is rendered, but content and line numbers are not visible until the component is clicked.

Before click:
[image]

After click:
[image]

Here's my JSF composite component template code:

```
<!-- INTERFACE -->
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="styleClass" type="java.lang.String" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="value" type="java.lang.Object" />
    <cc:attribute name="converter" type="java.lang.String" />
    <cc:attribute name="mode" type="java.lang.String" />
    <cc:attribute name="theme" type="java.lang.String" default="eclipse" />
    <cc:attribute name="lineNumbers" type="java.lang.String" default="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="matchBrackets" type="java.lang.String" default="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="matchTags" type="java.lang.String" default="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="closeBrackets" type="java.lang.String" default="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="closeTag" type="java.lang.String" default="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="activeLine" type="java.lang.String" default="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="indentUnit" type="java.lang.Integer" default="2" />
    <cc:attribute name="smartIndent" type="java.lang.Boolean" default="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="readOnly" type="java.lang.Boolean" default="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="electricChars" type="java.lang.Boolean" default="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="lineWrapping" type="java.lang.Boolean" default="false" />
    <cc:attribute name="firstLineNumber" type="java.lang.Integer" default="1" />
    <cc:attribute name="tabIndex" type="java.lang.Integer" default="0" />
    <cc:attribute name="undoDepth" type="java.lang.Integer" default="40" />
    <cc:attribute name="pollInterval" type="java.lang.Integer" default="100" />
    <cc:attribute name="extraKeys" type="java.lang.String" default="{}" />
</cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>

<!-- required imports -->

<h:inputTextarea id="cmTextArea" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
    styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}">
    <c:if test="#{not empty cc.attrs.converter}">
        <f:converter converterId="#{cc.attrs.converter}" />
    </c:if>
</h:inputTextarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var cmTextArea = $('.#{cc.attrs.styleClass}'),
        myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(cmTextArea[0], {
            value: cmTextArea.val(),
            mode: '#{cc.attrs.mode}',
            theme: '#{cc.attrs.theme}',
            lineNumbers: #{cc.attrs.lineNumbers},
            matchBrackets: '#{cc.attrs.matchBrackets}',
            matchTags: {bothTags: #{cc.attrs.matchTags}},
            autoCloseBrackets: #{cc.attrs.closeBrackets},
            autoCloseTags: #{cc.attrs.closeTag},
            styleActiveLine: #{cc.attrs.activeLine},
            indentUnit: #{cc.attrs.indentUnit},
            smartIndent: #{cc.attrs.smartIndent},
            readOnly: #{cc.attrs.readOnly},
            electricChars: #{cc.attrs.electricChars},
            lineWrapping: #{cc.attrs.lineWrapping},
            firstLineNumber: #{cc.attrs.firstLineNumber},
            tabindex: #{cc.attrs.tabIndex},
            undoDepth: #{cc.attrs.undoDepth},
            pollInterval: #{cc.attrs.pollInterval},
            extraKeys: #{cc.attrs.extraKeys}
        }); 
    });

</script>
```

Example of using composite component:

```
<t:codeMirror mode="text/xml" theme="cobalt"
                value="#{bean.content}" tabIndex="1" lineNumbers="true"
                converter="escapeConverter" electricChars="true" lineWrapping="true"
                extraKeys="{ 'F11': function(cm) {cm.setOption('fullScreen', !cm.getOption('fullScreen'));}, 'Ctrl-J': 'toMatchingTag','Ctrl-Space': 'autocomplete' }"
                matchBrackets="true" closeBrackets="true" matchTags="true"
                closeTag="true" styleClass="sampleClass" />
```

As I said, I cannot understand, why there's no content displayed (immediately) in my component (without clicking on it), placed in a (second - invisible at page load) tab while component, placed outside Primefaces' tabView is rendered properly (with content and line numbers).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:
I guess I need to call `refresh` when codemirror object gets visible (on tab show). Great, it works that way, but is there any way to include that call in a composite component itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See CodeMirror's [`refresh`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#refresh) method. The editor needs to be visible in order to draw itself, and if you initialize it in a hidden element, you have to call `refresh` the first time it becomes visible.

Comment: Ok, I added a `refresh` call when the second tab (p:tabView) becomes active (on tab show) and it works. The problem is that I have to make another JS function to make that call every time I use my composite component. Is there any way to include that call in component implementation?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, we haven't been able to find a sane way to get notified when a given DOM element becomes visible.

Comment: I guess I expected that... Anyway, thanks for your help. For now I'll leave this question opened and mark your answer as useful.

Comment: After thinking about this a little, I just added an addon that might help solve this (in a crude way, by polling). See [here](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_autorefresh)

Comment: Just tried your addon - apparently it works great! Thank you very much for your effort! Earlier today I was thinking about some kind of polling to detect when the component becomes visible but I just didn't make it work.